# Fabry-Perot Spectroscopy

Tags: optics, interference

Suppose you have a source of variable wavelength, and you are sweeping the wavelength while monitoring transmission through a Fabry-Perot cavity at normal incidence?

What (qualitatively) could you see if you doubled the length of the cabity?

Comment: More on [Fabry-Perot](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=Fabry-Perot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will see transmission peaks when integer multiples of the half-wavelength fit into the cavity length $L$. So, this means the condition (n is an integer):

$L = n \lambda /2$,

or:

$\lambda = 2 L / n$.

This is often expressed using "wavenumber" $1/\lambda$ (proportional to frequency), so that the spacing is even:

$\frac{1}{\lambda} = \frac{n}{2 L}$.

If you double the length, this wavenumber spacing will be twice as tight. A new transmission peak will appear exactly in between them all. If you look at wavelengths, you will keep the same transmission peaks, but gain new ones at intermediate wavelengths, although not centered perfectly because of the relations above.